# Oracle SQL string always missing expression inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, string, oracle, stored-procedures

I am currently resolving issues regarding stored procedure which has a string type of query. This is because of dynamic params like order by and keeps getting missing expression. I wonder where could be the issue in the query during parsing. Any idea?

BTW this is inside if else, almost identical below only few params, but this one is throwing exception

```
OPEN CUR_OUT FOR
            '  SELECT ' ||
          '  DISTINCT TB1.TB1_ID, '||
          ' TB1.TB1_PRN as prn, '||
          '  TB2.TB2_ENGISH_NAME AS MAIL_TYPE , TB1.TB1_REV_NAME AS ADDRESSEE, '||
          '  TB1.TB1_MAIL_DEST,TB1.COC_CODE, TB1.TB1_POSTAGE , TB1_STAMP_TYPE, TB1.TB1_ADDRESS, '||
          '    TB1.TB1_COLLECT_DATE_DT, TB1.TB1_REG_DATE_DT, TB4.TB4_BATCH_NO, TB1.TB1_CONFIRM_IC_DATE_DT, '||
          '    TB1.INS_CODE , TB1.TB3_ID, TB3.TB3_ENGISH_NAME AS STATUS, TB1.TB1_REMARK, TB1.MLT_ID, TB5.TB5_ID,'||
          '   TB5.TB5_HANDLED_BY, TB5.TB5_HANDLED_DATE_DT, TB5.TB5_PE_DATE_DT, TB5.TB5_DESCRIPTION, TB5.TB5_PE_DECISION, '||
          '    TB1.TB1_FOLLOWUP, TB1.TB1_FOLLOW_UP_DATE_DT, TB1.TB1_FOLLOW_UP_BY, '||
           '         NULL as location,'||
           '         NULL as workparty,'||
            '  TB1.INM_NO, TB1.TB1_SP_NAME, TB1.TB1_UN_VERIFIED_BY f_unveri_recorded_by, '||
            '  TB1.TB1_UN_VERIFIED_DATE_DT f_unveri_date, TB1.TB1_UN_VERIFIED_BATCH_NO f_unveri_batch ,TB1.TB1_RES_MAIL_CLERK,'||
             ' TB1.TB1_PRN_FOR_SORTING'||
           ' FROM TABLE_1 TB1'||
          ' JOIN TABLE_2 TB2 ON TB2.TB2_ID=TB1.MLT_ID AND TB2.TB2_MAIL_DIRECTION IN(''O'',''X'')'||
           ' JOIN TABLE_3 TB3 ON TB3.TB3_ID = TB1.TB3_ID'||
           ' LEFT JOIN TABLE_4 TB4 ON dsj.TB4_ID = TB1.TB1_BATCH_ID'||
           ' LEFT JOIN TABLE_5 TB5 ON TB5.TB1_ID = TB1.TB1_ID'||
           ' WHERE  '||
                ' ( ' || PARAM_1 ||' IS NULL OR TRUNC(TB1.TB1_COLLECT_DATE_DT) >= TRUNC('||PARAM_1 ||') )'||
             '   AND ( ' || PARAM_2 ||' IS NULL OR TRUNC(TB1.TB1_COLLECT_DATE_DT) <= TRUNC('||PARAM_2||') )'||
              '  AND ( '|| PARAM_3 || 'IS NULL OR TB1.INM_NO= '||PARAM_3 ||')'||
               ' AND ( '|| PARAM_4 ||' IS NULL OR TRUNC(TB1.TB1_REG_DATE_DT) >= TRUNC('|| PARAM_4 ||') )'||
              '  AND ( '|| PARAM_5 ||' IS NULL OR TRUNC(TB1.TB1_REG_DATE_DT) <= TRUNC('|| PARAM_5 ||') )'||
              '  AND ('|| PARAM_6 ||' IS NULL OR TRUNC(TB1_CONFIRM_IC_DATE_DT)= TRUNC(' || PARAM_6 ||' ) )'||
              ' AND ('|| PARAM_7 || 'IS NULL OR TRUNC(TB1.TB1_CONFIRM_IC_DATE_DT) <= TRUNC('|| PARAM_7 || ') )'||
              '  AND ('|| PARAM_8 ||'IS NULL OR TB1.COC_CODE= '|| PARAM_8 ||')'||
              '  AND ( '|| PARAM_9||' IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_REV_NAME= '|| PARAM_9 ||')'||
              '  AND instr(' || PARAM_10 || ', '',''||TB1.INS_CODE||'','') > 0 '||
              '  AND ( '|| PARAM_11 || 'IS NULL OR TB1.TB3_ID = ' || PARAM_11 ||' )'||
               ' AND ('|| PARAM_12 || ' IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_STAMP_TYPE= '|| PARAM_12|| ' )'||
               ' AND ('|| PARAM_13 || 'IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_POSTAGE= '|| PARAM_13 ||' )'||
              '  AND ( '|| PARAM_14 || 'IS NULL OR TB5.TB5_REASON_CODE= '||PARAM_14 ||')'||
              '  AND ('|| PARAM_15||' IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_LAST_REMARK= '||PARAM_15||' )'||
              '  AND ('|| PARAM_16 ||' IS NULL OR TB4.TB4_BATCH_NO = '||PARAM_16 ||')'||
              '  AND ('|| PARAM_17 ||' IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_CTB5IRM_IC_BY= '|| PARAM_17 ||' )'||
               ' AND ('|| PARAM_18 ||' IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_ADDRESS LIKE ''%''' || PARAM_18 || '''%'' )'||
              '  AND TB1.MLT_ID in (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('|| PARAM_19 ||', ''[^,]+'', 1, level) AS parts'||
              '      FROM dual CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('|| PARAM_19 || ', ''[^,]+'', 1, level) IS NOT NULL)'||
               ' AND TB1.TB1_PRN  like  decode('|| vConVal ||', null, ''%'', ''rem'', ''%-%'' )'||
              '  AND   TB1.TB1_PRN not like  ''%-%'''||
            ' ORDER BY '|| tempString ||' '||
               ' OFFSET ( '|| vPageNum || '- 1)* '|| vRowPerPage ||'   ROWS'||
                ' FETCH NEXT '||  vRowPerPage  ||'  ROWS ONLY'  ;
```

Comment: A wall of code will make most readers turn away. Make it easy to assist you, minimize the problem. Read [mcve] and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm.

Comment: My first guess is you're missing single quotes all over the place (unless all your `param_N` parameters are numbers). However, instead of concatenating your parameters in, why not use bind variables instead? It'll reduce the chances of SQL injection for a start, and you won't have to consider adding in single quotes all over the place, or worry about datatype conversions. So `... where :param_1 is null or col1 >= :param_1...`, and you'd call it like `open your_cursor for '<sql text>' using param_1, param_1, ...`

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the code at first glance, I can see few mistakes as follows:

```
'  AND ( '|| PARAM_3 || 'IS NULL OR TB1.INM_NO= '||PARAM_3 ||')'||
```

There should be space before `IS NULL` so that when your `PARAM_3` value is replaced with actual value lets say `PARAM_3 = 123` then it becomes `123 IS NOT NULL` instead of `123IS NOT NULL`:

```
'  AND ( '|| PARAM_3 || ' IS NULL OR TB1.INM_NO= '||PARAM_3 ||')'||
```

Same stands true for the lines with `PARAM_7, PARAM_8, PARAM_11, PARAM_13, PARAM_14`

Instead of directly opening the cursor with dynamic query, You can try to put it in `DBMS_OUTPUT` and check the correctness of the query. There might be the String parameter which you have not enclosed with single quotes and other errors can be easily detected if you have query(after parameters are replaced into it) is ready with you.

You can use the following query with visible issues resolved and check if it works for you:

```
OPEN CUR_OUT FOR '  SELECT '
                 || '  DISTINCT TB1.TB1_ID, '
                 || ' TB1.TB1_PRN as prn, '
                 || '  TB2.TB2_ENGISH_NAME AS MAIL_TYPE , TB1.TB1_REV_NAME AS ADDRESSEE, '
                 || '  TB1.TB1_MAIL_DEST,TB1.COC_CODE, TB1.TB1_POSTAGE , TB1_STAMP_TYPE, TB1.TB1_ADDRESS, '
                 || '    TB1.TB1_COLLECT_DATE_DT, TB1.TB1_REG_DATE_DT, TB4.TB4_BATCH_NO, TB1.TB1_CONFIRM_IC_DATE_DT, '
                 || '    TB1.INS_CODE , TB1.TB3_ID, TB3.TB3_ENGISH_NAME AS STATUS, TB1.TB1_REMARK, TB1.MLT_ID, TB5.TB5_ID,'
                 || '   TB5.TB5_HANDLED_BY, TB5.TB5_HANDLED_DATE_DT, TB5.TB5_PE_DATE_DT, TB5.TB5_DESCRIPTION, TB5.TB5_PE_DECISION, '
                 || '    TB1.TB1_FOLLOWUP, TB1.TB1_FOLLOW_UP_DATE_DT, TB1.TB1_FOLLOW_UP_BY, '
                 || '         NULL as location,'
                 || '         NULL as workparty,'
                 || '  TB1.INM_NO, TB1.TB1_SP_NAME, TB1.TB1_UN_VERIFIED_BY f_unveri_recorded_by, '
                 || '  TB1.TB1_UN_VERIFIED_DATE_DT f_unveri_date, TB1.TB1_UN_VERIFIED_BATCH_NO f_unveri_batch ,TB1.TB1_RES_MAIL_CLERK,'
                 || ' TB1.TB1_PRN_FOR_SORTING'
                 || ' FROM TABLE_1 TB1'
                 || ' JOIN TABLE_2 TB2 ON TB2.TB2_ID=TB1.MLT_ID AND TB2.TB2_MAIL_DIRECTION IN(''O'',''X'')'
                 || ' JOIN TABLE_3 TB3 ON TB3.TB3_ID = TB1.TB3_ID'
                 || ' LEFT JOIN TABLE_4 TB4 ON dsj.TB4_ID = TB1.TB1_BATCH_ID'
                 || ' LEFT JOIN TABLE_5 TB5 ON TB5.TB1_ID = TB1.TB1_ID'
                 || ' WHERE  '
                 || ' ( '
                 || PARAM_1
                 || ' IS NULL OR TRUNC(TB1.TB1_COLLECT_DATE_DT) >= TRUNC('
                 || PARAM_1
                 || ') )'
                 || '   AND ( '
                 || PARAM_2
                 || ' IS NULL OR TRUNC(TB1.TB1_COLLECT_DATE_DT) <= TRUNC('
                 || PARAM_2
                 || ') )'
                 || '  AND ( '
                 || PARAM_3
                 || ' IS NULL OR TB1.INM_NO= ' ---- Extra space added before IS
                 || PARAM_3
                 || ')'
                 || ' AND ( '
                 || PARAM_4
                 || ' IS NULL OR TRUNC(TB1.TB1_REG_DATE_DT) >= TRUNC('
                 || PARAM_4
                 || ') )'
                 || '  AND ( '
                 || PARAM_5
                 || ' IS NULL OR TRUNC(TB1.TB1_REG_DATE_DT) <= TRUNC('
                 || PARAM_5
                 || ') )'
                 || '  AND ('
                 || PARAM_6
                 || ' IS NULL OR TRUNC(TB1_CONFIRM_IC_DATE_DT)= TRUNC('
                 || PARAM_6
                 || ' ) )'
                 || ' AND ('
                 || PARAM_7
                 || ' IS NULL OR TRUNC(TB1.TB1_CONFIRM_IC_DATE_DT) <= TRUNC(' ---- Extra space added before IS
                 || PARAM_7
                 || ') )'
                 || '  AND ('
                 || PARAM_8
                 || ' IS NULL OR TB1.COC_CODE= ' ---- Extra space added before IS
                 || PARAM_8
                 || ')'
                 || '  AND ( '
                 || PARAM_9
                 || ' IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_REV_NAME= '
                 || PARAM_9
                 || ')'
                 || '  AND instr('
                 || PARAM_10
                 || ', '',''||TB1.INS_CODE||'','') > 0 '
                 || '  AND ( '
                 || PARAM_11
                 || ' IS NULL OR TB1.TB3_ID = ' ---- Extra space added before IS
                 || PARAM_11
                 || ' )'
                 || ' AND ('
                 || PARAM_12
                 || ' IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_STAMP_TYPE= '
                 || PARAM_12
                 || ' )'
                 || ' AND ('
                 || PARAM_13
                 || ' IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_POSTAGE= ' ---- Extra space added before IS
                 || PARAM_13
                 || ' )'
                 || '  AND ( '
                 || PARAM_14
                 || ' IS NULL OR TB5.TB5_REASON_CODE= ' ---- Extra space added before IS
                 || PARAM_14
                 || ')'
                 || '  AND ('
                 || PARAM_15
                 || ' IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_LAST_REMARK= '
                 || PARAM_15
                 || ' )'
                 || '  AND ('
                 || PARAM_16
                 || ' IS NULL OR TB4.TB4_BATCH_NO = '
                 || PARAM_16
                 || ')'
                 || '  AND ('
                 || PARAM_17
                 || ' IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_CTB5IRM_IC_BY= '
                 || PARAM_17
                 || ' )'
                 || ' AND ('
                 || PARAM_18
                 || ' IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_ADDRESS LIKE ''%'''
                 || PARAM_18
                 || '''%'' )'
                 || '  AND TB1.MLT_ID in (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('
                 || PARAM_19
                 || ', ''[^,]+'', 1, level) AS parts'
                 || '      FROM dual CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('
                 || PARAM_19
                 || ', ''[^,]+'', 1, level) IS NOT NULL)'
                 || ' AND TB1.TB1_PRN  like  decode('
                 || VCONVAL
                 || ', null, ''%'', ''rem'', ''%-%'' )'
                 || '  AND   TB1.TB1_PRN not like  ''%-%'''
                 || ' ORDER BY '
                 || TEMPSTRING
                 || ' '
                 || ' OFFSET ( '
                 || VPAGENUM
                 || '- 1)* '
                 || VROWPERPAGE
                 || '   ROWS'
                 || ' FETCH NEXT '
                 || VROWPERPAGE
                 || '  ROWS ONLY';
```

Comment: oh never have I tought of this. thanks a lot , I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1):

**NEVER** build queries using string concatenation to include values; that is how you introduce SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Instead, you can use bind variables:

```sql
OPEN CUR_OUT FOR
  q'[SELECT DISTINCT
         TB1.TB1_ID,
         -- all your columns
         TB1.TB1_PRN_FOR_SORTING
  FROM   TABLE_1 TB1
         JOIN TABLE_2 TB2
         ON TB2.TB2_ID=TB1.MLT_ID
            AND TB2.TB2_MAIL_DIRECTION IN('O','X')
         JOIN TABLE_3 TB3
         ON TB3.TB3_ID = TB1.TB3_ID
         LEFT JOIN TABLE_4 TB4
         ON dsj.TB4_ID = TB1.TB1_BATCH_ID
         LEFT JOIN TABLE_5 TB5
         ON TB5.TB1_ID = TB1.TB1_ID
  WHERE  ( :p01 IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_COLLECT_DATE_DT >= TRUNC(:p01) )
  AND    ( :p02 IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_COLLECT_DATE_DT <  TRUNC(:p02) + 1 )
  AND    ( :p03 IS NULL OR TB1.INM_NO = :p03 )
  AND    ( :p04 IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_REG_DATE_DT >= TRUNC(:p04) )
  AND    ( :p05 IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_REG_DATE_DT <  TRUNC(:p05) + 1 )
  AND    ( :p06 IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_CONFIRM_IC_DATE_DT >= TRUNC(:p06) )
  AND    ( :p07 IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_CONFIRM_IC_DATE_DT <  TRUNC(:p07) + 1)
  AND    ( :p08 IS NULL OR TB1.COC_CODE = :p08 )
  AND    ( :p09 IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_REV_NAME = :p09 )
  AND    ( ',' || :p10 || ',' LIKE '%,'||TB1.INS_CODE||',%' )
  AND    ( :p11 IS NULL OR TB1.TB3_ID = :p11 )
  -- More filters
  ORDER BY ]' || tempString || q'[
  OFFSET :pageOffset  ROWS
  FETCH NEXT :pageSize ROWS ONLY]'
  USING (
    PARAM_1, PARAM_1,
    PARAM_2, PARAM_2,
    PARAM_3, PARAM_3,
    PARAM_4, PARAM_4,
    PARAM_5, PARAM_5,
    PARAM_6, PARAM_6,
    PARAM_7, PARAM_7,
    PARAM_8, PARAM_8,
    PARAM_9, PARAM_9,
    PARAM_10, 
    PARAM_11, PARAM_11,
    -- more parameters for the other filters
    (vPageNum - 1)* vRowPerPage,
    vRowPerPage
  );
```

*Note:*

- Instead of using:

  ```sql
  ( :p01 IS NULL OR TRUNC(TB1.TB1_COLLECT_DATE_DT) >= TRUNC(:p01) )
  AND ( :p02 IS NULL OR TRUNC(TB1.TB1_COLLECT_DATE_DT) <= TRUNC(:p02) )
  ```

  Which would not be able to use an index on `TB1.TB1_COLLECT_DATE_DT` (and would need a separate function-based index on `TRUNC(TB1.TB1_COLLECT_DATE_DT)`), you can use:

  ```sql
  ( :p01 IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_COLLECT_DATE_DT >= TRUNC(:p01) )
  AND ( :p02 IS NULL OR TB1.TB1_COLLECT_DATE_DT <= TRUNC(:p02) + 1 )
  ```

  Which can use an index on `TB1.TB1_COLLECT_DATE_DT`.